# Simplest way to select a column in table A that need info from table B?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables:

Table A stores user info:

`Name | Sex | Location | Other | User_ID`

Table B stores private messages and sender, receiver of that message:

`Message_content | Sender_ID | Receiver_ID | Message_ID`

Now given a user(receiver) name, I want to get the message content and sender's Name, is it possible to get it done in one simple query?

My code below can only get the Message_content but not sender's name:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT PersonalMsg.content FROM PersonalMsg 
INNER JOIN UserDB ON UserDB.User_ID=PersonalMsg.Receiver_ID 
WHERE UserDB.Name = '$userName'");
```

Btw I just start Table B and please let me know if the design of this table is bad, I have little experience in designing database anyway. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Join the user table twice, once for receiver, and again for sender. You can (/will need to) assign table aliases to each of the instances, like `sender`,`receiver` to make it clear which is which.

Comment: You have to use Table A Primary in Table B in Database designing.

Comment: @Shahbaz yes, my User_ID in Table A is primary. So this is right way right?

Comment: yes, also you have to include it in Table B as Foreign key see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, by just adding another join:

`SELECT PersonalMsg.content, u2.Name FROM PersonalMsg  INNER JOIN UserDB u1 ON UserDB.User_ID=PersonalMsg.Receiver_ID  INNER JOIN UserDB u2 ON UserDB.User_ID=PersonalMsg.Sender_ID  WHERE u1.Name = '$userName'`

There are two things you should *really* change:

- stop use mysql_query() (use [pdo](https://www.php.net/pdo) instead)
- use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to mitigation sql injection attacks

Answer (score 1):

Join the `UserDB` table again on the `Sender_ID`.

Something like:

```
SELECT p.Message_content, u2.Name FROM PersonalMsg p
LEFT JOIN UserDB u1 ON u1.User_ID=p.Receiver_ID
LEFT JOIN UserDB u2 ON u2.User_ID=p.Sender_ID
WHERE u1.Name = '$userName'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Table A Primary in Table B in Database designing. then use

```
$resutl = "select a.name,b.Message_content from Table-A as a, Table-B as b where a.User_ID = b.User_ID";
```

Comment: Yours looks really concise but is it complete solution? I don't quite follow and I'm only providing receiver's name. What's b.User_ID?

Comment: you have to include it as foreign key in Table b to get data from bot tables, it is the right way of designing database.

Comment: Sry I'm still confused... Didn't I already include that in `Message_content | Sender_ID | Receiver_ID | Message_ID`